# Display fields based on Checkbox actions

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a VF page where I am using checkbox fiels, I want to display three other fiels if the checkbox is selected.

How can I go about doing that ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`rendered`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm) attribute on `<apex:inputfield>` or `<apex:inputtext>`. By setting this attribute, you can control whether or not a component appears on a Visualforce Page.

Include all fields that may or may not be shown on the Visualforce Page, but set `rendered="{!Object.YourCheckboxField}"` on the fields that you want to show/hide based on the checkbox field. Optionally, you can use a Visualforce [function](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm) like `IF` or `NOT`.

For example, if you wanted to show or hide the Email field on Contacts based on whether or not  the HasOptedOutOfEmail field is true or false, it would look like this.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="Custom Contact Visualforce Page" />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageblock>
            <apex:pageblocksection>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.FirstName}" />
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.LastName}" />
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.Phone}" />
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Contact.Email}" rendered="{!NOT(Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail)}" />
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but can I do this without creating pages (using apex) ?

Comment: You don't need to use Apex, but you do need to use Visualforce.

Comment: Read these documents then read my answer again (I updated it): [1](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputField.htm), [2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm)

Comment: Also, if this answer has helped you, please don't forget to click the checkmark next to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes of caurse, but I have an other question, where exactly I would put this code ?

Comment: In your Visualforce page, between the `<form>` tags.

Comment: Excuse me, but I just started with SF, I created my objects and for evry object I ceated its fields, but now I want to display this fields in one of my objects like I said, but I can't find the page of my object, in **Developer** > **Pages** I found nathing !

Comment: Oh, I see, by default the pages you view for each object are actually Page Layouts (found by going to Setup > Create > Objects > [Your Object] > Page Layouts or Setup > Customize > [Standard Object] > Page Layouts). Visualforce pages are separate, and you would need to create your own for this functionality to work (Setup > Develop > Pages > New). I updated my answer with some basics that should get you started. You should walk thru [this example](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_CSH.htm#pages_quick_start_hello_world.htm) 1st, tho. Also, read other articles in that doc.